# Slideshow with different amount of images per slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a slideshow. A normal slideshow has one image per slide, but in my case every slide has different amount of images.

Here is an example of 2 slides:

**First Slide**

[image: First Slide]

**Second Slide**

[image: Second Slide]

I've working fine with one image, but can't put with more than that per page.

```js
let currentSlide = 0;
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide")
const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot')

const init = (n) => {
  slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
    slide.style.display = "none"
    dots.forEach((dot, index) => {
      dot.classList.remove("active")
    })
  })
  slides[n].style.display = "block"
  dots[n].classList.add("active")
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init(currentSlide))
const next = () => {
  currentSlide >= slides.length - 1 ? currentSlide = 0 : currentSlide++
    init(currentSlide)
}

const prev = () => {
  currentSlide <= 0 ? currentSlide = slides.length - 1 : currentSlide--
    init(currentSlide)
}

document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener('click', next)

document.querySelector(".prev").addEventListener('click', prev)


setInterval(() => {
  next()
}, 5000);

dots.forEach((dot, i) => {
  dot.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(currentSlide)
    init(i)
    currentSlide = i
  })
})
```

```css
.slide-container .prev,
.slide-container .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.slide-container .prev:hover,
.slide-container .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}

.slide-container .prev {
  left: 2px;
}

.slide-container .next {
  right: 2px;
}

.dots-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dots-container .dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #dfd6ce;
}

.dots-container .dot.active {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  /*   background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #accbee 0%, #e7f0fd 100%); */
}

body h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.slide-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.slide-container .slide {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide-container .slide.fade {
  animation: fade 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53) both;
}

.slide-container .slide img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Image Slider</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Image Slider</h1>
  <div class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide fade">
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590595978583-3967cf17d2ea?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class="slide fade">
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588807308097-fb6e5047df8c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class="slide fade">
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589808710416-24cf7ac026f2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class="slide fade">
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588796388882-a4d533c47e5e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="prev" title="Previous">&#10094</a>
    <a href="#" class="next" title="Next">&#10095</a>
  </div>
  <div class="dots-container">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If anyone can help, it will help a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Show what you've attempted so users can grow from what you have. No one will do it for you but we are kind and will assist.

Comment: Updated, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting more than one image per slide is to put several img elements in the slide and size them accordingly.

This snippet is just basic - put two imgs into the first slide and give them 45% width each (so they have room to be next to each other).

Depending on how general you need to be you will have to do some sort of calculation for each slide which calculates the relevant width for each image in it, possibly just 100/n% of the slide's width, but maybe more complex if your images are of different aspect ratios.

```js
let currentSlide = 0;
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide")
const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot')

const init = (n) => {
  slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
    slide.style.display = "none"
    dots.forEach((dot, index) => {
      dot.classList.remove("active")
    })
  })
  slides[n].style.display = "block"
  dots[n].classList.add("active")
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init(currentSlide))
const next = () => {
  currentSlide >= slides.length - 1 ? currentSlide = 0 : currentSlide++
    init(currentSlide)
}

const prev = () => {
  currentSlide <= 0 ? currentSlide = slides.length - 1 : currentSlide--
    init(currentSlide)
}

document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener('click', next)

document.querySelector(".prev").addEventListener('click', prev)


setInterval(() => {
  next()
}, 5000);

dots.forEach((dot, i) => {
  dot.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(currentSlide)
    init(i)
    currentSlide = i
  })
})
```

```css
.slide-container .prev,
.slide-container .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.slide-container .prev:hover,
.slide-container .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
}

.slide-container .prev {
  left: 2px;
}

.slide-container .next {
  right: 2px;
}

.dots-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dots-container .dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #dfd6ce;
}

.dots-container .dot.active {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  /*   background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #accbee 0%, #e7f0fd 100%); */
}

body h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.slide-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.slide-container .slide {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide-container .slide.fade {
  animation: fade 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53) both;
}

.slide-container .slide img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Image Slider</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Image Slider</h1>
  <div class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide fade">
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590595978583-3967cf17d2ea?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='' style="width: 45%; height: auto;">
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588807308097-fb6e5047df8c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt='' style="width: 45%; height: auto;">
    </div>
    <div class="slide fade">
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588807308097-fb6e5047df8c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class="slide fade">
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589808710416-24cf7ac026f2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class="slide fade">
      <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588796388882-a4d533c47e5e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ' alt=''>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="prev" title="Previous">&#10094</a>
    <a href="#" class="next" title="Next">&#10095</a>
  </div>
  <div class="dots-container">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```